# Can I steal anything without repercussions?

Tags: the-witcher-3

When I arrived in the first village, the tutorial popups warned me that I should be careful not to do anything that would draw the attention of the guards. I ignored this advice and went right to looting the houses in the village and taking anything that isn't nailed down.

This doesn't seem to have any effect so far, and no repercussions. Can I really just loot anything, or are there some things that will trigger a response if I loot them? Are there any indirect consequences of stealing everything in the game?

Comment: Stealing never had a consequence in W1+2. Merely drawing your sword can be deadly though..

Comment: From playing The Witcher 2, "don't draw the attention of the guards" basically means don't get into any fights or anything. Looting has no repercussions, you can even do it right in front of other NPCs and nobody cares.

Comment: Mad Scientist, could you choose one of these answers as accepted?

Answer (score 27):

There are definitely repercussions.

I looted some things in the military camp near the first village, wanting to see if there were any repercussions (keeping in mind I did it in plain sight) and I promptly got my arse handed to me by the entire encampment.

They took some cash from my pockets and rather than reloading from last save, I 'woke up' in the encampment (sort've like how dying in GTA and other games works) and they weren't aggressive towards me any more.

Comment: Confirmed on Blood & Broken Bones! difficulty.

Comment: Confirmed on Normal difficulty as well

Comment: +1 for the "arse" reference, because I saw what you did there

Answer (score 17):

Witcher 3 isn't like Skyrim where if you steal you are considered a Thief and get a bounty on your head.

**EDIT**: There have been some developments folks! I was just playing and if you try and loot at the Nilfgaardian Camp in White Orchard in front of the guards they will become aggressive and put you down. You wont die. What happens to you is described below. (**NOTE:** I'm playing in Blood & Broken Bones Difficulty)

> About the warning, imagine you draw the sword and attack people, the
>   guards will be aggressive towards you aswell and attack you. If you
>   lose an animation plays out where they dump you and steal some orens
>   from you (and you actually lose orens).

If you kill a goose for example a message appears that you're causing problems and the guards may be agressive towards you :D I mean I would be pissed too if someone killed my goose :D

It's a nice little touch from CDPR and that's why they warn you about that.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you are unseen by soldiers / guards you can steal whatever you want! You can go into people's houses and steal their stuff right in front of them.

If you are in a camp or town by it's guards, the whole regiment (but not the whole faction I belive) will chase you down. For example I stole something in the Nilfgaardian camp in White Orchard and the soldiers from the camp chased me through the swamp. We passed some other patrolling nilfaardians, but the patrollers were not aggresive.

I don't know exactly how far NPCs will chase you or when it's safe to return to an area.

Answer (score 1):

Containers near guards will trigger warning when opened and guards start attack you if you pick anything from then.

Such containers marked with glove when looked at by witcher sense.

Not sure if it is line-of-sight or distance determined.

Answer (score 0):

On PS4 I've seen that sometimes when you open a container when guards are nearby you will get a warning that if you take something they could get aggressive. I noticed it the first time at the baron's castle. My guess is that you can always take what you want except when a warning is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can steal around guards just get ready to run away really fast. Once at a safe distance wait for the fight music to stop then the guards will go back to docile mode.